# Developing a Hashing Algorithm: RGB Color ID and String to Int 

Tags: c++, arrays, string, colors, hash

In a program I am writing, I would like to develop a hashing algorithm which can map either a RGB color, string, or both to a unique and relatively small index.

The goal here is to reduce as many collisions as possible, with the guarantee that no two colors being passed through the algorithm will be similar (perceptually; e.g. red, blue, orange).

With my limited knowledge, the array seems the optimal choice for a direct-access data structure, but I do not want to create an incredibly large array. Given that I have to allocate memory in C++ for the array, I am having trouble developing such an algorithm.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Does the RGB color have 8bits per color element? (24bits total). Then I dont see the point hashing it. Also, why dont you just use CRC32 for example? You can hash any data with it. But as said, its pointless to hash data that is smaller or equal than 32bits with CRC32.

Comment: It does have 8 bits per element. Pardon my asking, but why would there be no point hashing it? I'm still figuring stuff out, as you can see.

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of all this? I am having trouble understanding why do you need hashing. Do you just want to access some array element by some random value, for example do you want to do something like: `elements["color_string_here"] = 1337` and `elements[0xFE63AA37CB] = 1337`, and then later access that element and get the `1337` value...?

Comment: The purpose of hashing is to squeeze larger data into simple value that can be quickly compared. If the value is for example 32bits in size, there should be no need to hash it, since you can easily compare 32bits values. But i have no clue what you are trying to do, maybe you want 16 bit or 8 bit hashes? I dont know.

Comment: I have a class "Subject" which has two objects associated with it: a string label and a color (8-bit RGB). In my program, I need to have some collection of said Subjects, from which I can readily and swiftly access a Subject by either its color or label.

Comment: Does "Subject" have either a name or a color or both at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `std::map` to access the `Subject` by its color or label. No need to develop own hashing algorithms for that, all you have to do is to create comparison operator, which should be easy on this case, assuming you use 32bit integer for the RGB color, and a `std::string` for the `label`.

**Edit:** Actually you dont need to make anything else than the map (no custom operators), as simple as:

```
typedef map<int, MyClass*, greater<int> > IntClassMap;
typedef map<std::string, MyClass*, greater<std::string> > StrClassMap;
IntClassMap inttable;
StrClassMap strtable;

void adding_the_data(){
    inttable[0x11223344] = myclasspointer1;
    inttable[0x11223345] = myclasspointer2;
    inttable[0x11223346] = myclasspointer3;

    strtable["test string1"] = myclasspointer1;
    strtable["test string2"] = myclasspointer2;
    strtable["test string3"] = myclasspointer3;
}

void accessing_example(){
    strtable["test string1"]->something;
}
```

`std::map` is very fast, I don't think you need (or find) any faster solution than that.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you chose greater as a comparator? It defaults to less, from what I can see.

Comment: @JTCho, I have always used greater for some reason I cannot remember anymore, I think I had some problems so I chose `greater` for some unknown mysterious reason. But I guess it works with `less` too.